# Plane wave propagating in de Sitter spactime

Tags: general-relativity, gravitational-waves

Around a flat background, a plane wave propagating in the $z$ direction is given by 
$h_{\mu\nu} = \epsilon_{\mu\nu} \cos(\omega t -kz)$.

What is the generalisation of this to a de Sitter background?

Comment: @J.G.: That is for a scalar field. Presumably OP is interested in gravitational waves.

Comment: Yes, I am interested in gravitational wave propagation.

Answer (score 0):

To lowest order in $\Lambda$, i.e. taking the metric to be Minkowski plus a perturbation from $\Lambda$, plus a perturbation from the plane wave, the plane wave is given in the following papers

[The fate of a gravitational wave in de Sitter spacetime](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0809.2945.pdf)
[About the propagation of the Gravitational Waves in an
asymptotically de-Sitter space](http://inspirehep.net/record/1094333/files/arXiv%3A1203.4305.pdf)